# Still using "public String(char* value)" nowadays?

Tags: c#, string, unsafe, null-terminated, unsafe-pointers

I came across(inside(definition) of the string "class"(.NET)):

```
public String(char* value);
```

What is written in the commentary:

```
    // Parameters:
    //   value:
    //     A pointer to a null-terminated array of Unicode characters.
```

My questions:

Can I use it only in an unsafe context, does it still make sense to use that String(char* value) nowadays or is this just a relict from the past, based on this "ABC\0"(termination of that string) ?

If I can/should use it, how and what would be a situation for this method ?

Comment: @Nishant. I thought inside of  e.g. "unsafe{ char c='G'; char * pc=&c;  Console.Writeline(c);}"  it looks more than c/c++ than c#, espeially the syntax reminds me of that.

Comment: Pretty much a relic of the past, used to ease people from C++ code to C# code. I suppose it might be useful in some rare cases to do with P/Invoking unmanaged code and getting null-terminated strings back, but normally you'd be able to set thing up so the marshaller would handle that for you.

Comment: Note that it is C# `char`, so a unicode string... in C/C++ it would be `wchar_t`. If you want "8 bits strings" there is another group of constructors that accept `sbyte*`

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have two possible scenarios:

1. **You don't need to work with unsafe code.** If you don't need to work with unsafe code, don't use unsafe code. You will never use this string constructor.
2. **You need to work with unsafe code.** If you need to work with unsafe code and `char*` for some reason¹, this method allows you to "convert" a `char*` to a standard .NET string after you are done with your unsafe operations.

¹ Possible use cases for unsafe code are outside the scope of this question.